# ValueError: The view did not return an HttpResponse object

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, httpresponse

I am writing a Django server. I had to use generic views for my API class. Now, Whenever I test the code using postman, everything works fine. But if I test it using other clients like Talend API tester or my Chrome browser, it returns 500 Error saying API did not return any HttpResponse object. Here's my skeleton codebase

**If I disable csrf_exempt, I get csrf_exempt error. If I enable it, I get the class returned None.**

```
@method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name='dispatch')
class ClassName(View):
    
    @throttle
    def post(self, request) -> JsonResponse:
        try:
            data = (json.loads(request.body))
        except JSONDecodeError:
            # decoding error of Json File.
            msg = "An error occurred while decoding the input"
            return message_handler(msg, 500)
        
        number = data.get("number", None)


        if number is None:
            msg = "number key is missing from the payload"
            return message_handler(msg, 400)
    
        if len(number) == 0:
            msg = "number number cannot be an empty string"
            return message_handler(msg, 400)
    
        if len(number) > 30:
            msg = "Maximum 30 characters are supported for car number key"
            return message_handler(msg, 400)
        
        ......
        some other application logic
        ......
        
        return JsonResponse({
            "status": True,
            "message": "",
        }, status=200)


def message_handler(message: str, status_code: int, status: bool = False) -> JsonResponse:
    return JsonResponse({
        "status": status,
        "message": message,
    }, status=status_code)
```

All of my API is using the same format, they are returning a JsonResponse, so what am I doing wrong?

Update #1:
Message handler is a generic function. There are five other responses, all reply using generic functions. code updated.

**Update #2**

Error seems to be with the decorator (throttle). so here's throttle code:

```
def throttle(function):
    @functools.wraps(function)
    def wrapper(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            last_request_at = request.session[LAST_REQUEST_KEY]
        except KeyError:
            last_request_at = None
        
         reequest.session[LAST_REQUEST_KEY] = last_request_at
         return function(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

If put `@method_decorator(throttle, name='post')` on the class, I get the following error

```
TypeError: wrapper() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'
```

Comment: What's `message_handler` and are there any other returns?

Comment: @KlausD. I have updated the question with more codes.  `message_handler` is a generic function that returns a `JsonResponse` object.

Comment: If you're accessing it using Chrome, are you just doing a GET request?  You don't have def get() implemented, or @require_http_methods, so that would return an error.

Comment: @TimNyborg I am using an app on Chrome which is sending Post Requests. I have other classes which have the same issue. Does `csrf_excempt` can do a problem with it?

Comment: @O_o what output does print(type(number)) give you? Write it just after `number = data.get("number", None)`.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat the code doesnot go upto that point.

Comment: @O_o what is that decorator `throttle` which you are using? Try `@method_decorator(throttle)` instead of `@throttle` since it is decorating a method.

Comment: Issue with the `throttle` decorator. If I remove it, everything works perfectly. If I put it in `@method_decorator(throttle, name='post')`, then it shows the following error: 

`TypeError: wrapper() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'`

Comment: @O_o in the line `reequest.session[LAST_REQUEST_KEY] = last_request_at` is `reequest` the actual code or an error while editing the question? If it is actually that then that is a typo (it should have been `request`).

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat, Thank you for staying with me. The problem was with `throttling` decorator. I forgot to send any response from one of the if condition. and yes, that was a typo indeed. when I removed most of my throttling code.